# rational approximation for $x^x$

Tags: functions, inequality

Using the standard method with derivatives (and taking logarithm of both sides first) we can prove that $x^x>\frac{1}{2-x}$ for $x\in(0,1)$ - this inequality is an exercise from a problemset.

Is it possible to replace $\frac{1}{2-x}$ with a rational function $R$ satisfying $R(0)=1$ ?

The inequality $x^x>R(x)$ should work for $x\in(0,T)$ with some $T>0$, not necessarily $T=1$.

I tried with homographies at first, later with some random examples and looking at plots, but without success.
I only managed to came arbitrarily close with homographies: for any $c<1$ there is $T>0$ such that $x^x>c\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ on $(0,T)$; unfortunately the inequality $x^x>\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot estimate $f(x) = x^x$ from below by any function $R$ which is differentiable at $x=0$ and satisfies $R(0)=1$. That would imply
$$
 \frac{x^x-1}{x} \ge \frac{R(x)-1}{x}
$$
on some interval $(0, T)$, but for $x \to 0$ the right-hand side tends to $R'(0)$, whereas the left-hand side tends to $-\infty$.